# Select word from MS Word through VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop

I want to **select** specific word from Ms Word through VB.NET (*Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word*).

Any idea how to do it?

**EDITED:**
Problem is that I can not find/replace string more than 255 symbols. That's why I'm trying find another solution for this issue.

Comment: have you tried anything? if so, do post your work and any error that you might be facing..

Comment: @Nadeem_MK, commented to your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**if someone looking solution for this issue:**

```
Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
Dim WordApp As Word.Application = New Word.Application
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document

Public Function FindReplaceText(CellsValueWithLabel As String()()) As Boolean
    'Find and replace texts from arrays
    For Each cellsValue In CellsValueWithLabel
        Try
            If cellsValue(1).Length < 255 Then
                If WordDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:=cellsValue(0), ReplaceWith:=cellsValue(1), Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll) Then
                    logHistory.insertLogHistory(Chr(34) + cellsValue(0) + Chr(34) + " - replaced by " + Chr(34) + cellsValue(1) + Chr(34))
                End If
            Else
                Dim myRange = WordDoc.Content
                While myRange.Find.Execute(FindText:=cellsValue(0))
                    If myRange.Find.Found Then
                        myRange.Select()
                        My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(cellsValue(1))
                        WordApp.Selection.PasteAndFormat(Word.WdRecoveryType.wdPasteDefault)
                        logHistory.insertLogHistory(Chr(34) + cellsValue(0) + Chr(34) + " - replaced by " + Chr(34) + cellsValue(1) + Chr(34))
                        Clipboard.Clear()
                    End If
                End While
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            logHistory.insertLogHistory("********** ERROR ********** " + cellsValue(0) + " " + ex.Message.ToString())
        End Try
    Next

    WordDoc.Save()
    Return True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems quite vague but as a beginning, you may proceed as follows;

```
        Dim objWord As New Word.Application  
        Dim WordToFind as string = "Test"
        objWord.Visible = True 

        'Open an existing document.  
        Dim objDoc As Word.Document = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\folder\MyDoc.doc")  
        objDoc = objWord.ActiveDocument  

        'Find word
        objDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:=WordToFind)  

        ' perform your process with the searched text

        'Close the document 
        objDoc.Close()  
        objDoc = Nothing 
        objWord.Quit()  
        objWord= Nothing
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have same code. Problem is that I can not find/replace string more than 255 symbols. That's why I'm trying find another way for solution this issue.

Comment: Ohh.. may be you need to edit your question and mention it ;)

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anybody, to replace more than 255 characters, using range would help.

```
 If (SomeText.Length < 250) Then
    oSel.Find.Execute("SomeText", , , , , , True, Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue, , "Replacetext", Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
    Else
        Dim rng As Word.Range = oSel.Range
        rng.Find.Execute("SomeText", , , , , , , , , , )
        rng.Text = DirectCast(StringWithMoreThan255Characters, String)

 End If
```